# Encoding issue in httpheader result in struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, encoding, struts2

I am sending in an struts 2 application the message of a custom error in the heading. I've done it by adding to the struts.xml file a global result like:

```
<global-results>
    <result name="badDataError" type="httpheader">
       <param name="status">500</param>
       <param name="headers.errorMessage">${exception.message}</param>
    </result>
</global-results>

<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping result="badDataError" exception="mypackage.BadDataException" />
</global-exception-mappings>
```

so when I throw an exception like

```
throw new BadDataException("my error message");
```

then that message is included in the header of the file so it can be read in a json as an error:

```
$.ajax(
    { 
        url: ...,
        type: "POST",
        data: ...,
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            alert("save works");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var errorMessage = XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('errorMessage'); 
            var message = "There has been an error";
            if (errorMessage != null){
                message = message + ':<br/>'+errorMessage;
            }
            alert(message);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }
);
```

This works, but whenever I send a message with any special character (e.g. á é ñ ...) it's not shown correctly neither in the alert or by displaying the variable with console.log(), though if I use firebug there the message is shown correctly, as if it wasn't using the correct encoding in javascript.

I've tried to set in the ajax call

```
contenType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
or
contenType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1'
```

but without any success.

How can I know which encoding it's being used for the error message and the header and being able to choose a different one for it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use any contenttype in ajax. I do not know it may not work but try at least without setting content type.

Answer (score 0):

Header field encoding for non ASCII-text is defined here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt

It's not that hard to read, there you'll find your answer. An example for an encoded header field is

```
 =?iso-8859-1?q?this=20is=20some=20text?=
```

Comment: The response is a json and I'm reading the header with jQuery, I don't really know what to do with your answer. Can you elaborate on it? thanks.

Comment: This is the way that header fields need to be encoded server-side. I'm not sure how struts handles this internally. But Firebug seems to decode right. What exactly does the wrongly displayed value look like?

Comment: That's the problem I don't know how to change that. And what is really more strange is that sending the same message I see different symbols each time in the alert. For example sending a message which starts with "El número" in the alert is shown "El n慧ꄀᏏႨ჌", if I try again I see "El nھﾇ钨ڶ㌈ሌﾂﾄ焀ใ"... so weird.